# How to import a certificate in java?

Tags: java, import, certificate

I got a certificate .cer and I'd like a script to import it in the Trusted Publisher list of certificate.

I managed to do this thing in C#

```
X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(filePath.Text, "Telecomitalia1?12524", X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet);
X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.TrustedPublisher);
store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
store.Add(certificate);
store.Close();
```

Is there a way to do the same in Java?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5):

You can do the equivalent in Java. Check out the [MSCAPI](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/security/#1) provider.

> Provides direct read-write access to MS Window's keystores. The Windows-MY keystore contains the user's private keys and the associated certificate chains. The Windows-ROOT keystore contains all root CA certificates trusted by the machine.

```
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-ROOT");
// Note: When a security manager is installed, 
// the following call requires SecurityPermission 
// "authProvider.SunMSCAPI".
ks.load(null, null);
ks.setCertificateEntry("alias", cert);
ks.store(null, null); //again the permissions here...
```

Answer (score 2):

The way java handles certificates is very different to how Windows handles certificates. Windows provides predefined stores for certificates for the machine account, user accounts and service accounts, and distinguishes certificates based on their purpose (e.g. personal vs trussted CA.)

Java simply provides the concept of the Keystore - an arbitrary file of your choosing where certificates are stored. There is a default keystore used by the JDK for trusted CAs, located at`$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts`.

To import the certificate into a keystore, you can use the keytool that is shipped with the JDK - which keystore you use depends upon your application.

See

- [KeyTool](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/keytool.html)
- [Most common keytool commands](http://www.sslshopper.com/article-most-common-java-keytool-keystore-commands.html)

Comment: Although cacerts is the native Java way to go, you can use the MSCapi provider to access/modify Windows' root certificates.

Comment: I got a Java desktop application; at a given point I create a JFrame and within it I open a Internet Explorer Browser in order to connect to a web application. In some pages Java Applets signed with the certificate we are talking about must be executed. I'd like to insert that certificate within a list of trusted publishers, like I could do with C#. Is there anything I can do? Can I use a java keystore? Which one? Thanks alot.

Comment: Lorenzo that's another question.

Answer (score 1):

Using the [keytool](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/keytool.html), like the [Java tutorial explains](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/toolsign/rstep2.html) so well.

Comment: It doesn't explain how to add to Windows' trust store.

Comment: Is the question how to add a certificate to Windows ? Or how to add a certificate to the runtime used to execute a program ? considering the question was on Java scope, I choosed to answer the second part of the question.

Comment: I want to add this certificate so that when an applet is executed I avoid the pop-up asking for execution permission. I've tried adding my cert to cacerts with java keytool but I think I'm missing one more step, since I still get a confirmation pop-up. This happens, I think, because cacerts keystore does not get used by Internet Explorer (nor FireFox) when checking for certificate permission. Is there anything I can do or adding my cert to cacerts keystore is simply the wrong solution?