# Access Personal Certificate from windows using java

Tags: java, certificate, digital-certificate

I have a digital certificate installed in my Local system. Manually in windows  i am able to access the certificate in Personal folder using certmgr.msc .(Not sure about the location of the file)
How do I access the same certificate using java program?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to import a certificate in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7232310/how-to-import-a-certificate-in-java)

Comment: Are you simply looking to find the location of the certificate file?

Answer (score 2):

I think it can be achieved using "Windows-MY" keystore type:

KeyStore personalKS = KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-MY");

Please see the ["Access Microsoft CryptoAPI and Its Cryptographic Services" section of the "Leveraging Security in the Native Platform Using Java SE 6 Technology" Oracle's article](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/security-137537.html#1).